# Getting instanceof operator to work with multiple super classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, instanceof, duck-typing

Imagine the following JavaScript example scenario:

1. We model things that can appear in a plane (like shapes or points)
2. Some of that things (like circles) can have a label

Given the following code implementation (Circle inherits from both Shape and Labelable) **how can I get every circle to be instanceof both Shape and Labelable using `instanceof` operator?**. Please note that code relative to methods is not relevant in this example, but it should be inherited.
    function Shape(area){
        this.area = area;
    }

```
Shape.prototype.sayArea = function(){
    alert('My area is ' + this.area);
};

function Circle(area, center, label){
    Shape.call(this, area);
    Labelable.call(this, label);
    this.center = center;
}

Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

Circle.prototype.sayCenter = function(){
    alert('My center is ' + this.center);
};

function Labelable(label){
    this.label = label;
}

Labelable.prototype.sayLabel = function(){
    alert('My label is ' + this.label);
};

Circle.prototype.sayLabel = Labelable.prototype.sayLabel;

var c = new Circle(100, [0, 0], 'myLabel');

c instanceof Circle; // True
c instanceof Shape; // True
c instanceof Labelable; // False although we have used .call() and prototype is also inherited , how to make it true?
```

Comment: You can't because the prototype chain don't know about `Labelable`

Comment: The prototype chain is a single list. The only way to do that is to have one of the superclasses be a subclass of the other.

Comment: @ArunPJohny or Pointy if you want please provide an answer explaining why it is not possible so I can mark it as accepted. Pointy workaround is not valid as not all the shapes are Labelables and not only shapes can have labels.

Comment: @Pointy or ArunPJohny remember that you can still post an answer explaining why it is not possible so I can accept it. Currently there is an answer but doesn't talk about the problem (instanceof operator) but about prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using a library that has `extend` functionality to add multiple prototypes to an object.

Comment: As far as I know prototype will be inherited but it won't solve the problem related to insntanceof operator. Others has commented that it cannot be solved.

Comment: What about object.getPrototypeOf? Object has its own set of tools that might be alternative.

Comment: Would that help to solve the problem with `instanceof` operator? If so, how? Otherwise you can explain why it is not possible to solve the `instanceof` operator problem and I'll acept your answer.